# ASP.NET MVC: how to get form attributes from ViewContext/FormContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Let's say I have an asp.net mvc application. It contains a view with two html forms:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("act", "ctrl", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form1" })) {
    @Html.TextBox("name");
    ...
}

@using(Html.BeginForm("act2", "ctrl2", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "form2" })) {
    @Html.TextBox("name2");
    ...
}
```

And a controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Act() {
  //...
}
```

I agree, it's a bit strange, but is it possible to get information about the form id in `public ActionResult Act()` when the form is submitted? May I can use `FormContext` or `ViewContext` to achieve it?

Comment: You not adding a 'form attribute' - you adding a route value. And if you add a parameter to the method, it would bind to that parameter - `public ActionResult Act(string id) {` (the value of `id` would be `"form1"`)

Comment: Oh, sorry, I've missed a form method. Updated.

Comment: Based on your edit you are now adding a html attribute. And no, you cannot get the value of a html attribute in the POST method (but why would you want to anyway?)

Comment: based on your code, those forms are submitting to different controllers and actions. Is that intended?

Comment: Use hidden field in form and read it in action like ordinary property of your viewmodel.

Comment: Yes, hidden field is a good idea. I'll try it. Thanks.

Comment: No need for a hidden input - you can just add it as a route value (your original code)

Comment: Finally it's your choice: send it in url or in form body.